# Python get all values that is a word from 2nd column from .csv file

Tags: python

**Goal:**

My goal is to get words out of second column from CSV. I am having a difficulty searching for what I need, I am also not familiar with data when using Python.

Reason I am doing this is, because of the following:

We have a database ran by an external company. Within one of the tables, one of the columns should only be barcodes.

**Here is the problem:**

I have a .csv file with this data:

```
columnOne,columnTwo
"YOBA001OL","501",
"YOBA001OL","Yo Bakehouse",
"WILD004OL","Wild",
"TWOB009OL","7897",
"S079R36D05","0007",
```

How can I extract only values that is a "word" in the 2nd column and not numbers?

Here is my desired output:

```
columnOne,columnTwo
"YOBA001OL","Yo Bakehouse",
"WILD004OL","Wild",
```

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
import csv


with open('barcodes.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Do you already have code to parse your CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing, check if it is an int

```py
output = []
for row in csv_reader:
    try:
        int(row[1]) # second column
    except:
        output.append(row)

print(', '.join(output))
```

Comment: I think your first answer was better. Thats the one I have used but amended this:         `except:
            print(row[0] +', '+ row[1])`

Comment: I edited so you have the desired output. I've saved into a variable in case you'd want to write it back to a CSV, it would be easier

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
with open('barcodes.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        if not row[1].isdigit():
            print(row)
```

Comment: This won't work with negative number though

Comment: @politinsa why not?

Comment: @LV98 because "-1".isdigit() is False